# Django DRY Models

Tags: django, django-models

In general, how can I keep my models DRY when I have to repeat several attributes multiple times?

For example:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street_nr = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street_nr = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Normalize your database structure, you could normalize Address even further

```
class Adress(models.Model):
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street_nr = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Adress, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Adress, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: But if we have the same address for the person and the event or 2 events have one address. We shouldn't delete event on cascade...

Answer (score 0):

Just add refs:

```
class AdressData(models.Model):
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street_nr = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address_data = models.ForeignKey('AdressData')

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address_data = models.ForeignKey('AdressData')
```

Answer (score 0):

Django models can use Python's object inheritance to share common data; with a provision. These are referred to as [abstract models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

To refactor your code using an abstract models I would write it like so:

```py
class BaseAddressModel(models.Model):
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street_nr = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Event(BaseAddressModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Person(BaseAddressModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Previous answers might serve your purpose better, but this is an option.